# How can user make iOS 5.1 UIKit UIDatePicker component return time differing in AM/PM from the time selected

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uikit, uidatepicker

I use [UIDatePicker component](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Art/datepicker_a.jpg) from iOS 5.1 library for selecting datetime value which is on button action read from self.datePicker.date, formatted and displayed within the label on the iPhone simulator. Everything works fine.

When I push hour and/or minute wheel more strongly, it takes several seconds before it stops and selects a new time. If the hour turning wheel cross the AM/PM boundary, the AM/PM wheel changes its state automatically. Still OK.

BUT when I change AM/PM wheel before the other two wheels stop, the change is not reflected by date picker and it will return the opposite AM/PM time to what is selected (provided the hour wheel did not accidentally initiated another AM/PM transition to equal it to the one just selected).

Can you please confirm I'm not mistaken and advice how to foolproof this component?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the same behavior in the datetimepicker for a new appointment, so it seems to be a quirk of how the control is implemented. I'm not sure how big a problem it is, as spinning multiple wheels simultaneously is not exactly a common usage pattern for a datetimepicker.

Comment: strings42: Thanks for the answer. I've posted it as an iPhone [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone_thankyou.html) to Apple.